# basic math problem with Integer and NSDecimalNumber - Invalid operands to binary

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Man the simplest stuff always seems so crazy in Objective-C to me, anyways I need to do some basic subtraction and multiplication and am stumped.

I have:

```
client.PricingDiscount <-- this is an Integer 16 property on a CoreData NSManagedObject
sku.RetailPrice <-- this is a Decimal property on a CoreData NSManagedObject
```

I am simply trying to get a NSDecimalNumber to display like so:

```
NSDecimalNumber *showPrice = sku.RetailPrice * (100 - client.PricingDiscount);
```

I have tried a bunch of different forms of this and cannot figure out what the hell I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard operators cannot be used with `NSDecimalNumber`

```
NSDecimalNumber *one = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:100] decimalValue]]; 
NSDecimalNumber *factor = [one decimalNumberBySubtracting:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[client.PricingDiscount decimalValue]]];
NSDecimalNumber *showPrice = [sku.RetailPrice decimalNumerByMultiplying:factor];
```

Comment: I'd suggest creating an NSDecimalNumber from an NSString value of @"100" for the first line, in order to avoid any floating point errors from creeping in.

Comment: Conversion from an int to an NSDecimalNumber is lossless even with floating point, in this case--100 is directly representable by all the primitive types, including `double` and `float`.

Answer (score 3):

`NSDecimalNumber` is an object wrapper for a number--you are treating it like a C value.  Instead, try:

```
float price = [sku.retailPrice floatValue] * (100 - [client.pricingDiscount floatValue]);
NSDecimalNumber *showPrice = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:price];
```

It's confusing, but `NSNumber` and `NSDecimalNumber` are Objective-C wrappers for C types, typically used for storage in container objects such as `NSArray` (or Core Data).  `NSInteger` and `NSDecimal`, on the other hand, are C types (`NSInteger` just maps to `int`).

**EDIT:** falconcreek's answer is better for avoiding accuracy loss.  When working with integers, though, you'll typically use unboxed C types.

Comment: Risking loss of precision converting retailPrice to a float. Stick with `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: falconcreek's right, the whole reason you'd want to use an NSDecimalNumber for currency is to avoid floating point errors in your calculations.  See his answer for a more precise way of doing this.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there's no autoboxing in Objective-C. One of the things I miss most from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDecimalNumber *showPrice = sku.RetailPrice * (100 - client.PricingDiscount);
```

`NSDecimalNumber` is a class. What you are doing here is calculating a value, and then assigning that to be the value of a pointer to an `NSDecimalNumber` object. This is bad mojo.

I haven't used `NSDecimalNumber` before, but if you need that particular object, what you want is something like this:

```
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(sku.RetailPrice * (100 - client.PricingDiscount))];
NSDecimal* decimal = [number decimalValue];
NSDecimalNumber* showPrice = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:decimal];
```

Comment: (sku.RetailPrice * (100 - client.PricingDiscount) 
--> RetailPrice is an instance of NSDecimalNumber this will not work